# Why my "Add to cart" button is not working in product page?

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

Add to cart button not working in my product page. But my test server is working fine, I copied and pasted the code as it is but, onclick event hasn't fire...

Comment: Check any error in console and log file @YKB

Comment: Are you using any custom theme?

Comment: My Theme is RWD...

Comment: Is it a ajax action?

Comment: @RintoGeorge, yes it was a ajax action.

Comment: Could you please check in the error console/network tab to see what is happening once you press the add to cart button?

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved here are the steps to do:

Go for var/www/html/app/design/frontend/your theme/template/checkout/cart.phtml

Check the functionality after  tag
Under checkout directory verify the sub directories called "view", "onepage" etc.

Look at the "controller.php" file in the "checkout"
Path:

/var/www/html/app/code/local/Mworks/Ajax/controllers/IndexController.php
check Line: 29, 30

```
 $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                                array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
                        );
   $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
```